# Image gallery table reflowing

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here's one of my web pages:

http://isometricland.net/artwork/artwork.php

How do I make the tables containing the image thumbnails and descriptions reflow when the browser window is small? (For instance, mobile devices.)

Is there a way to do it without JavaScript? Can this be done with inline DIVs and still look the same?

Thanks.

[edit]

Here's what two "rows" of thumbnails look like, minus the URLs:

```
<table class="stab">
    <tr>
        <td class="a2x1"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="" border="0" alt="HSL Sphere (SVG; thumbnail)" /></a></td>
        <td class="a1x1"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="" border="0" alt="RGB Cube (SVG; thumbnail)" /></a></td>
        <td class="a4x3"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="" border="0" alt="Color solid comparison" /></a></td>
        <td class="a7x6"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="" border="0" alt="Colored mind" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="">HSLSphere</a></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="">RGBCube b</a></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="">Color solid comparison</a></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="">Colored mind</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><i>(Facial portrait by another author.)</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="a1x1"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="" border="0" alt="Munsell color solid cylinder" /></a></td>
        <td class="a1x1"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="" border="0" alt="Munsell color solid sphere" /></a></td>
        <td class="a1x1"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="" border="0" alt="Camera focal length effects" /></a></td>
        <td class="a1x1"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="" border="0" alt="Graphical projection comparison" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="">Munsell color solid cylinder</a></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="">Munsell color solid sphere</a></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="">Camera focal length distance</a></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="">Graphical projection comparison</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The table is also contained within another DIV that centers the table's alignment.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see in the code, there are two rows of data, but six rows of HTML markup. I am willing to change this so that they are equal.

Comment: try `float: left`

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns

Comment: Raptor: I tried using a left float, but then the rows are not centered. @Scott: I asked to not use JavaScript.

Comment: @Scott: Also, those suggestions do not help because my tables have no headers, and are used purely for presentation.

Comment: The reality is.. that layout could quite easily be pulled off without the use of tables.

Comment: Yes, I know. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The table won't reflow (ie, wrap onto new lines), because it's a table. Setting `max-width:100%` and `height:auto` on the images will help somewhat, but at truly small device sizes it won't be practical to have four columns.

Why not wrap the contents of each cell in a `<div>` element with...

```
div{
    height: /* some declared height */;
    width:  25%; /* four cells per row */
    float:left;
    padding: 10px; /* for legibility */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* so padding counts toward declared dimensions */
}
```

...and let the page reflow naturally?

Comment: I also want the to be cells centered in the container DIV. Using `float:left` or `display:inline-block` seems to cause the cells to be mashed to the left side with a lot of empty space on the right side. I would like to fix that.

Comment: Declare the width of each cell as a percentage, and center the text and image within them.

Comment: What percentage? E.g. on wide screens I will maybe want five cells per row. On small screens I may be limited to two or even one. Do I use 20% for the former and 100% for the latter?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Set "box-sizing:border-box;" as well if you intend to add padding to the cells.

Comment: I guess with media queries this may be possible. I do *not* want to use JavaScript.

Comment: What you're trying to do is very simple and requires nothing but correct CSS.